# xml - grab subsubchild and collapse within child even when element text missing

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I have a nested xml data set like the one below that I am trying to parse w/ **xml2** and **tidyverse** packages.   There are three child envelopes.  I want to grab all the text for the `<card-id>` and `<value>` subsub child tags within each `<envelope>` tag and collapse them with a readily identifiable separator like `;;;` or make a list of data.frames out of them.

### MWE: Here's the data:

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

myxml <- read_xml('
<inside>
 <envelope>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">605380</card-id>
       <value>coke</value>
       <random></random>
     </card-entry>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">610954</card-id>
       <value>pizza</value>
       <random>false</random>
     </card-entry>  
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">605381</card-id>
       <value>surprise</value>
     </card-entry>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">610958</card-id>
       <value>joke</value>
       <random>true</random>
     </card-entry> 
 </envelope>
 <envelope>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">605381</card-id>
       <value>charlie horse</value>
     </card-entry>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">605380</card-id>
       <value>rug bug</value>
     </card-entry>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">610954</card-id>
       <value>mario cart</value>
     </card-entry>  
 </envelope>
 <envelope>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">605377</card-id>
       <value>trogdor</value>
     </card-entry>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer"></card-id>
       <value>jorb</value>
     </card-entry>
     <card-entry>
       <card-id type="integer">605333</card-id>
       <value></value>
     </card-entry>    
 </envelope>
</inside>
'
)
```

### Desired output:

```
c(
    "605380;;;coke;;;610954;;;pizza;;;605381;;;surprise;;;610958;;;joke",
    "605381;;;charlie horse;;;605380;;;rug bug;;;610954;;;mario cart",
    "605377;;;trogdor;;;;;;jorb;;;605333;;;"
)
```

Or just as good (maybe better) a nested list like this:

```
[[1]]
  card_id    value
1  605380     coke
2  610954    pizza
3  605381 surprise
4  610958     joke

[[2]]
  card_id         value
1  605381 charlie horse
2  605380       rug bug
3  610954    mario cart

[[3]]
  card_id   value
1  605377 trogdor
2    <NA>    jorb
3  605333    <NA>
```

I thought I could use `as_list` on the child and then use `xml_find_all` to create a list of data.frames but the `as_list` + `lapply` doesn't attack just one `envelope` but does them all with each pass through (I'd be nice to know what I'm missing about this function too).

### What I tried

```
myxml %>%
    xml_find_all('//envelope') %>%
    as_list() %>%
    lapply(function(x){
        data_frame(
            card_id = x %>% xml_find_all('//card-id') %>% xml_text(),
            value = x %>% xml_find_all('//value') %>% xml_text()
        )
    })
```

Comment: You turn it into a list just before sending it into lapply which is why it does it to everything. That is what the pipe operator does ( ` %>% ` ) push things forward to the next step, and lapply iterates over a list each time looking at the current X which is each one of the envelopes you fed it so it acts with `xml_find_all__`  on all of them.If you want more control, save the envelopes into a variable as a list, then use a loop to iterate with control and exert logic statement to parse the children, or build a complex function which you test extensively  & feed it carefully into lapply.

Comment: If you'd like to compare to the XML package, try `lapply(myxml["//envelope"], xmlToDataFrame)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly pretty, but you can get the list of data.frames by first getting all the children of each envelope into separate list elements, then looping through to get the text from each card-id and value node.

```
myxml %>%
    xml_find_all('//envelope') %>%
    lapply(xml_children) %>%
    lapply(function(x) data.frame(
        card_id = xml_child(x, 'card-id') %>% xml_text,
        value = xml_child(x, 'value') %>% xml_text
        )
    )

#[[1]]
#  card_id    value
#1  605380     coke
#2  610954    pizza
#3  605381 surprise
#4  610958     joke
#
#[[2]]
#  card_id         value
#1  605381 charlie horse
#2  605380       rug bug
#3  610954    mario cart
#
#[[3]]
#  card_id   value
#1  605377 trogdor
#2            jorb
#3  605333
```

For the NAs instead of "", you could add `%>% ifelse(. == "", NA, .)` after each `xml_text`

Comment: Beautiful.  Helps me understand what I wasn't understanding about the structure as well.